Potential Syscall Note Loophole?
Linux has a syscall note which says

This exception is used together with one of the above SPDX-Licenses to mark user space API (uapi) header files so they can be included into non GPL compliant user space application code.

What is preventing someone from transferring the complete code of linux into the uapi header files and then using linux in a manner that is not compliant with GPL? What about someone distributing new code only in the uapi headers and nowhere else?

To my way of thinking, much the same thing that stops you from copying the whole of the kernel source into an MIT program, and claiming it's all now MIT.
Sure, the place you're copying it into has a more free license than the place you're copying it from, but that doesn't mean you can copy somebody else's code from one to the other with no consequences.  The code you're copying is under straight GPL, with no exception, and since you're not the sole rightsholder,  you have no power to add such an exception to it.
If you do what you describe, you won't create a non-GPL copy of the kernel, you'll create a GPL-with-no-exception set of header files.

What about someone distributing new code only in the uapi headers and nowhere else?

If you're the sole rightsholder, sure, you can add new code to the header files under GPL-plus-exception terms.  But right now, you can add completely-new code to the regular kernel under even more permissive terms, say MIT, if you want.  That doesn't mean the kernel folks will accept it under MIT, or continue to distribute it under MIT even if they do, but you're free so to add it, if you want.
To me, this looks like another of those complications that come from the "coloured bricks" model of copyright; again, I suggest that the "multiple coloured tarpaulins" model works better, and deals better with this question, too.

Thanks for the answer that answers it quite well. I will read the link you suggested now.

You're very welcome.  If you're happy with the answer, may I request that you accept it, by clicking on the tick outline next to it?  That puts the question to bed, signalling that you've had the question answered to your satisfaction, and drives the reputation system for both of us.  My apologies if you're already familiar with that aspect of SE site mechanics.
